# change background color with transition Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `li` which has `white` as a primary class.

**HTML**

```
 <li class=white></li>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('li').removeClass("white").addClass("blue");
               },4000);
```

I want the class change made a transition between both colors. Otherwise this script just hide and show the raw colors without any transition...suggestions?

Comment: jquery UI includes there, eg: https://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: It's a really bad idea to name classes after the appearance. If you want transition on the `<li>` element, just use `li { transition: all .5s linear }`, for example—that's not knowing what you are transitioning: background color? Color? Border color?

Comment: ok...after clicking a button I change the class name of an specific `li` and this element that originally is white have to fade to blue. I need Jquery. I would need to redefine everything if use Css

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS add `transition` to your classes. Check the snippet.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   $("li").removeClass("white").addClass("blue");
},4000);
```

```css
li{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.white{
background: #ddd;
transition: all 1s;
}

.blue{
background: blue;
transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="white"></li>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Furthermore, you could reduce the removeClass() and addClass() to a single toggleClass()

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Quotation Marks:

```
<li class="white"></li>
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, why quotation marks are so important? I made another question a while ago and I had the same feedback....